# Interface Builder encoding

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, interface-builder, xib

According to [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/SubclassingNSView/SubclassingNSView.html), Interface Builder instantiates objects, which then are serialized and packaged into a NIB/XIB file at design time. At runtime, the whole object graph is deserialized via *initWithCoder:*.

Here's the documentation:

> View instances that are created in Interface Builder don't call initWithFrame: when their nib files are loaded, which often causes confusion. Remember that Interface Builder archives an object when it saves a nib file, so the view instance will already have been created and initWithFrame: will already have been called.

As the objects are instantiated via *initWithCoder:*, I thought that the object graph is serialized via its counterpart *encodeWithCoder:*. However, consider the following code:

```
@interface CustomView : UIView
@end

@implementation CustomView

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
    if(self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]){
        NSNumber * n = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"DummyKey"];
        NSLog(@"%@", n);
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder{
    [super encodeWithCoder:aCoder];
    [aCoder encodeObject:@YES forKey:@"DummyKey"];
}

@end
```

If I place this CustomView on a storyboard in Interface Builder, it prints *"(null)"* instead of *"YES"*. Why is this happening? How does Interface Builder serialize the object graph? Am I misinterpreting the documentation?

Comment: Note that you can add "User Defined Runtime Attributes" in IB (select the view and go to the 3rd tab of the inspector). These will be set on your object when it is unarchived IIRC (using the setter method of your property).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`encoderWithCoder:` method won't be called because the time when XCode encode the object graph into xib is not running time, it can't call your `encoderWithCoder:` method.

`How does Interface Builder serialize the object graph?`

If you open Xib as source code, you can see it like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="4514" systemVersion="13B42" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none">
    <dependencies>
        <deployment defaultVersion="1536" identifier="iOS"/>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="3747"/>
    </dependencies>
    <objects>
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFilesOwner" id="-1" userLabel="File's Owner" customClass="EMXibViewController">
            <connections>
                <outlet property="view" destination="1" id="3"/>
            </connections>
        </placeholder>
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="-2" customClass="UIResponder"/>
        <view contentMode="scaleToFill" id="1">
            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="320" height="568"/>
            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
            <subviews>
                <view contentMode="scaleToFill" id="XyJ-CF-vRx">
                    <rect key="frame" x="68" y="102" width="204" height="403"/>
                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                    <color key="backgroundColor" white="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                </view>
            </subviews>
            <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
            <simulatedStatusBarMetrics key="simulatedStatusBarMetrics"/>
            <simulatedScreenMetrics key="simulatedDestinationMetrics" type="retina4"/>
        </view>
    </objects>
</document>
```

We can see xib only keeps the **non-default** value of object and the relationships between them.

The xib an UIViewController and has only two UI object , one is the UIViewController's view, the other is it's subview let's say it `mysubview` and talks about how XCode archive `mysubview`.

I have changed its backgroundColor、frame and autoresizingMask property of `mysubview`, take `backgroundColor` property as example, the backgroundColor property is saved as "color key="backgroundColor" white="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"". It will archive the backgroundColor of `mysubview`.

Xib just archive the backgroundColor and autoresizingMask and frame property of the `mysubview` object and when load the xib, it will call UIView's `initWithCoder` method. In the method, it will get the UIColor object for the key @"backgroundColor" and CGRect for the key @"frame" and  UIViewAutoresizing for the key @"autoresizingMask", any other property of UIView assigned default value.

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder] ;
    UIColor * backgroundColor = [aDecoder decodeIntegerForKey:@"backgroundColor"] ;
    if (backgroundColor) {
        self.backgroundColor = backgroundColor ;
    } else {
        self.backgroundColor = $(defaultColor) ; // if no key in xib, use the default value.
    }
    // more...
    return self ;
}
```

It's a nice question and make me think more.

Comment: @TamásZahola I have updated my answer which maybe more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Interface Builder doesn't use your code to generate xibs. It's as simple as that. `encodeWithCoder` is never called by the Interface Builder. The Interface Builder doesn't run your code.

Comment: Then why does the Apple documentation say the following: *"Remember that Interface Builder archives an object when it saves a nib file, so the view instance will already have been created and initWithFrame: will already have been called."* ?
It clearly states that the view is instantiated via *initWithFrame:* and is then archived into the NIB.

Comment: @TamásZahola Note that Interface Builder doesn't create your own class instances. If you choose a `UIView` from the library and change its class to `MyView`, no `MyView` is created. It will still be only a `UIView` for the interface builder. Interface builder doesn't run YOUR code.

Comment: @Sulthan However, IB does instantiate your private classes. If you override UIView with MyView and override the required init(coder:) method in your custom view, your intercept *will* be invoked.

Comment: @clearlight this answer is 8 years old.

Comment: @Sulthan: I realize that, not to impugn or judge, just to say 'this is how it is (now)'

Answer (score 0):

In simple word if you create your object in xib or Storybord then *initWithFrame* and *initWithCoder* will not be able to override by you, they will be called by framework and create the object property from xib or Storybord.